# How to wait for an async function to give response while running unit tests python

Tags: python, unit-testing, async-await, mocking, pytest

I am new to python. I have an async function for which I am trying to write unit tests.

I am stuck on how to wait for the function to return the response and use it to execute the next lines of code.

```
async def fetch_data(self, text, session):
    response = None
    payload = {"text": text.encode("ascii", "ignore").decode()}
    try:
        response = await session.post(url=self.embedder_endpoint, json=payload)
        response.raise_for_status()
        logger.info(f"Response status ({self.embedder_endpoint}): {response.status}")
    except Exception as err:
        logger.error(f"An error ocurred: {err}")
    assert response.status == 200
    response_json = await response.json(content_type=None)
    return response_json
```

I found couple of answers which says I can use `asyncio.get_event_loop()` but I did not understand how to use it in the unittests. The examples are little complex for my level of experience with python.

Therefore, I am posting this question.

I tried writing the below tests but nothing works as I feel I have some gaps with my understanding. Appreciate it if anyone could help me understand what is the mistake I am doing.

```
@mock.patch('aiohttp.ClientSession')
def test_fetch_embedding_failure(m_clientsession):
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as ex:
        text = "sample"
        bulk_embedder = BulkEmbedder(embedder_endpoint=embedding_endpoint)
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        m_post = mock.MagicMock(side_effect=Exception)
        m_clientsession.return_value.post = m_post
        loop.run_until_complete(bulk_embedder.fetch_embedding(text, m_clientsession))

@mock.patch('aiohttp.ClientSession')
def test_fetch_embedding_result(mock_session):
    text = 'a'
    json = {'test': 'value'}
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    mock_session.return_value.post = mock.MagicMock(status=200, json=json)
    response = loop.run_until_complete(mock_session.return_value.post.return_value)
    loop.close()
    logging.info(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to mock `aiohttp` in order to capture outgoing request and fake responses without actually sending HTTP requests over the wire than this open source should be useful: [aioresponses](https://github.com/pnuckowski/aioresponses)